# How to use static resource image without import in LWC Dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, images

I am calling a apex controller in lwc component to get the required image's `static resource name` & I want to use that `Image` in LWC component. Since I can't import the independent static resouce dynamically I wonder if I can use that static resource image `without importing`.

if can, then kindly suggest how?

I tried using Visualforce's `URLFOR($Resource[StaticResourceName_variable])`, but didn't work.

**Note:** All the Images StaticResources must be independent Resource.
I cannot have a common zip-folder where I can put all these images together & then use them with single import,like suggested here  [How can I dynamically load a static resource image in LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278296/how-can-i-dynamically-load-a-static-resource-image-in-lwc)

Comment: This [Thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278296/how-can-i-dynamically-load-a-static-resource-image-in-lwc) might be similar Please check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I dynamically load a static resource image in LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278296/how-can-i-dynamically-load-a-static-resource-image-in-lwc)

Comment: I cannot have a common zip-folder where I can put all these images together & then use them with single import,like suggested here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278296/how-can-i-dynamically-load-a-static-resource-image-in-lwc

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR use `/resource/staticResourceName` URL without import

**Explanation**

When a static resource is imported in LWC the the import variable contains url  as `'/resource/' + timestamp + staticresourceName` for example-

```
import logoImage from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/org1Logo';
```

then the `logoname` will contain the url as follow-

```
logoImage = '/resource/1675163571000/org1Logo'
```

here `1675163571000` is time-stamp for version of Static Resource and you can ignore this if you are not updating the target static resource

**ALternative & Perfect Solution**

you can query the whole url from apex controller like this-

```
StaticResource static_resource = [  SELECT Name,Id, SystemModStamp
                                    FROM StaticResource 
                                    WHERE Name = 'staticResourceName'
                                    LIMIT 1];

String url_file_ref = '/resource/'
                      + String.valueOf(((DateTime)static_resource.get('SystemModStamp')).getTime())
                      + '/' 
                      + static_resource.get('Name');
```

`url_file_ref` will be same when you will import the same resource in lwc, so you can use this in same manner, like

```
  <img src={url_file_ref} alt="" />
           
               or

loadScript (this, url_file_ref)
          .then (() => {
            console.log ('url_file_ref loaded');
          })
             .catch (error => {
               console.error ('url_file_ref : ' + error);
          }),
```